# PHP Multitasking/Multithreading

Tags: php, multithreading, multitasking

I’m dealing with this for the first time so I’m not sure how to implement it.
So I receive data via XML feed from URL and my code right now looks like this:

```
$products_url = ‘here comes URL to XML’;
$products = DcXmlToArray($products_url);
if(isset($products[‘product’]) && !empty($products[‘product’])) {

foreach($products[‘product’] as $key => $product) {

  $img_url = 'another URL for images...'; 
  $images = DcXmlToArray($img_url);
           foreach($images['image'] as $image) {
              //doing some work in here
            }
}
```

function DcXmlToArray looks like this:

```
function DcXmlToArray($url) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url, ‘SimpleXMLElement’,LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
return $arr;
}
```

And it all works very slowly (especially because of this URL with images) and I contacted support and there they told me to try multithreadingand they gave me this [LINK](https://www.mullie.eu/parallel-processing-multi-tasking-php/)

But I’m not sure how to implement this into my code.
Thanks.

Comment: so, you mean this `function DcXmlToArray($url)` is the function that makes the program solwer?

Comment: This function only converts the XML I get over the URL into an array which I then use to print on my webpage. 
The problem is actually that it all takes a long time to load because I have a loop in the loop and the other one that retrieves the images slows down because some product can have 15-20 images at a time.

Comment: rather than using multithreading you can do asynchronous prohgramming in php...it's being used a lot now a days, take a look at [reactphp](https://reactphp.org/) or [swoole](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.swoole.php).